# Copy values only to new workbook from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Suppose I have a `workbook1.xlsm` with multiple worksheets and full of various formulas. I want to create a new `workbook2.xlsx` which would look *exactly* the same as `workbook1` but in all the cells would be values instead of formulas.

I have this macro to copy one sheet from `workbook1`:

```
Sub nowe()

Dim Output As Workbook
Dim FileName As String

Set Output = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Przestoje").Cells.Copy

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "worksheet2.xlsx"
Output.SaveAs FileName

End Sub
```

but the problem is it copies only one worksheet and does not name it like it was in `worksheet1`. I cannot figure it out.

Yet another problem is that `worksheet2` is being opened afterwards. I do not want to do this.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do that as simply as possibly, without creating new workbook and copying sheets to it.

Few simple steps: `taking into consideration thisworkbook >> for each worksheet within thisworkbook >> copy+paste values of used range within worksheet >> save as new workbook as xlsx type >> open back base workbook >> and finally close one we created.`

The code will be simple and looks as follows:

```
Sub nowe_poprawione()

    Dim Output As Workbook
    Dim Current As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Set Output = ThisWorkbook
    Current = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim SH As Worksheet
    For Each SH In Output.Worksheets

        SH.UsedRange.Copy
        SH.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

    Next

    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "worksheet2.xlsx"
    Output.SaveAs FileName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open Current
    Output.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This should allow you to keep all the formatting, column widths, and only the values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyAll()

Dim Output As Workbook, Source As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String
Dim firstCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook

Set Output = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim i As Integer

For Each sh In Source.Worksheets

    Dim newSheet As Worksheet

    ' select all used cells in the source sheet:
    sh.Activate
    sh.UsedRange.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    ' create new destination sheet:
    Set newSheet = Output.Worksheets.Add(after:=Output.Worksheets(Output.Worksheets.Count))
    newSheet.Name = sh.Name

    ' make sure the destination sheet is selected with the right cell:
    newSheet.Activate
    firstCell = sh.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Address
    newSheet.Range(firstCell).Select

    ' paste the values:
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

Next

' delete the sheets that were originally there
While Output.Sheets.Count > Source.Worksheets.Count
  Output.Sheets(1).Delete
Wend
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "worksheet2.xlsx"
Output.SaveAs FileName
Output.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work to cycle through and copy all sheets after adding the workbook:

```
dim i as integer
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Select
    Cells.Copy

    Output.Activate

    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = Output.Worksheets.Add()
    newSheet.Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name

    newSheet.Select
    Cells.Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

Next
```

Note that this doesn't handle removing default sheets that automatically get created when the workbook gets created.

Also, `worksheet2` is actually being opened (though not named til `SaveAs`) as soon as you call this:

```
 Set Output = Workbooks.Add
```

Just close it after saving:

```
 Output.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work to cycle through and copy all sheets after adding the workbook - it builds on mr.Reband's answer, but with a few bells and whistles. Among other things it will work if this is in a third workbook (or an add-in etc), it deletes the default sheet or sheets that were created, it ensures the order of the sheets is the same as the original, etc:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyAll()

Dim Output As Workbook, Source As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String
Dim firstCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook

Set Output = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim i As Integer

For Each sh In Source.Worksheets

    Dim newSheet As Worksheet

    ' select all used cells in the source sheet:
    sh.Activate
    sh.UsedRange.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    ' create new destination sheet:
    Set newSheet = Output.Worksheets.Add(after:=Output.Worksheets(Output.Worksheets.Count))
    newSheet.Name = sh.Name

    ' make sure the destination sheet is selected with the right cell:
    newSheet.Activate
    firstCell = sh.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Address
    newSheet.Range(firstCell).Select

    ' paste the values:
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

Next

' delete the sheets that were originally there
While Output.Sheets.Count > Source.Worksheets.Count
  Output.Sheets(1).Delete
Wend
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "worksheet2.xlsx"
Output.SaveAs FileName
Output.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```