# copying worksheet values from one workbook to another vb.net without formula links

Tags: vb.net, excel

Using vb.net. we want to copy several worksheets from one file into another file.  we have it looping and copying which ones we have going by

```
 xlWorksheetSource.Copy(After:=xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets(xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Count))
```

for example... but i noticed when i open up the file that was created.. in some of the columns it has links that reference the original file for formulas... how can you just have it so it copies the values and doesn't reference the original file in formulas that it copied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy values only to new workbook from multiple worksheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251457/copy-values-only-to-new-workbook-from-multiple-worksheets)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Save values (not formulae) from a sheet to a new workbook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922374/save-values-not-formulae-from-a-sheet-to-a-new-workbook)

Comment: ya i can't seem to get a complete answer that is working though

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something like this

```
xlWorksheetSource.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False)
```

For more information use this link:
[ExcelPasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)