# Paste special values from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code to copy-paste all worksheets from one workbook to another.

I can't remove the formulas (paste special).

I tried a lot of paste special code, nothing worked

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim destWB As Workbook
Dim sourceWBSheet As Worksheet
Dim sheetIndex As Integer
sheetIndex = 1

Set sourceWB = Workbooks("template.xlsm") 'Asssume destination workbook is non-existent
Set destWB = Workbooks.Add
destWB.SaveAs "I:\PROJECT - Dashboard\2019JUNE"

For Each sourceWBSheet In sourceWB.Worksheets
    sourceWB.Activate
    sourceWBSheet.Select
    sourceWBSheet.Copy Before:=destWB.Sheets(sheetIndex)
    sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1
Next sourceWBSheet

End Sub
```

Expectation - when pasted to the destWB, only values remain (formulas are removed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy values only to new workbook from multiple worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251457/copy-values-only-to-new-workbook-from-multiple-worksheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub copyws()
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    Dim sourceWBSheet As Worksheet


    Set sourceWB = Workbooks("template.xlsm")    'Asssume destination workbook is non-existent
    Set destWB = Workbooks.Add
    destWB.SaveAs "I:\PROJECT - Dashboard\2019JUNE"

    For Each sourceWBSheet In sourceWB.Worksheets
        Set destWS = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set destWS = Sheets(sourceWBSheet.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If destWS Is Nothing Then
            Set destWS = destWB.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            destWS.Name = sourceWBSheet.Name
        End If
        sourceWBSheet.Cells.Copy
        destWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        destWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Next sourceWBSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Working now without formulas. However, Is there any way for me to keep the format / Table / font? I just want to remove the formulas